# How to add columns/rows to an existing empty JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am developing a software for which I need a basic Java Swing UI. I am using Netbeans which enables me to drag and drop UI component. However there is a final result table that I need to display using code.

In my UI using trhe IDE I created a `JTabbedPane`, inside which I added an empty `JTable` (no rows nor columns) called `finalOutputTable`. Now I want at runtime to fill this table, let's say with columns: x, y and rows: row1, row2 & row3.

How can I do that by coding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make a custom [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) that will allow you to support this functionality. `JTable` is just there to display the table on the GUI. The `TableModel` has all the business logic of what the data is and how each cell should act. To do this you will have to step away from the GUI-Builder and write actual code.

Tutorial: [Creating a Table Model](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Answer (score 3):

> inside which i added an empty JTable (no rows nor columns) called "finalOutputTable".

You need to add the data to the TableModel. Then you use:

```
table.setModel(...);
```

to display the data. You may also need to revalidate() the panel containing the table if you didn't reserve space for the table when you created the form.

Answer (score 2):

> How can i do that by coding?

See the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) lesson of the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a TableModel witch does all that hard work for you.
https://github.com/MarkyVasconcelos/Towel/wiki/ObjectTableModel